# Unable to resolve service for type xxx.'Infrastructure' while attempting to activate 'xxx.Infrastructure.TagRepository'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am getting the below error. I am using .Net Core web API.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'xxx.Infrastructure.Data.xxxContext' while attempting to activate 'xxx.Infrastructure.Repository.TagRepository'.

**Api Controller**

```
namespace xxx.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Default")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DefaultController:ControllerBase
    {
         private ITagRepository _tagRepository;
        public DefaultController(ITagRepository tagRepository)
    {
         _tagRepository = tagRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetAllUserInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            var Tags = _tagRepository.GetAllTagsByInstanceId("");
            if (Tags == null)
            {
                Tags = new List<TagEntity>();
            }
            return Tags.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
        services.AddSingleton<ModulePermissionHelper>();
        services.AddScoped<ITagRepository, TagRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ITagModuleRepository, TagModuleRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

**ITagRepository**

```
public interface ITagRepository
{
    List<TagEntity> GetAllTagsByInstanceId(string instanceId);
}
```

Comment: Where you registered `xxx.Infrastructure.Data.xxxContext`?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Are you referring to startup.cs

Comment: @HarshW, yes, it may be  `Startup.cs` or some other place

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Please refer attached Startup.config. I am using the below lines to register.

`services.AddScoped<ITagRepository, TagRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<ITagModuleRepository, TagModuleRepository>();`

Comment: You should also register `xxx.Infrastructure.Data.xxxContext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the exception message and the shown startup, the DI container is unaware of the required dependency in order to properly activate the desired type.

You need to register the DbContext with its associated configurations during startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
    services.AddSingleton<ModulePermissionHelper>();
    services.AddScoped<ITagRepository, TagRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ITagModuleRepository, TagModuleRepository>();

    //..
    services.AddDbContext<xxxContext>(options => ...);
}
```

Documentation: [Using DbContext with dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection)